# I am trying to get answer in json format but it simply returns a String.What am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, json, string

I am trying to get answer in json format but it simply returns a String.What am i doing wrong?

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import mysql.connector
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

def createConnection():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(user="akshay", password="akshay", host="localhost", database="BOOKS")
    return connection

@app.route("/contact")
def getContacts():
    print(request)
connection = createConnection()
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT ID, NAME, AUTHOR, SUBJECT, PRICE FROM BOOKS;")

contacts = []
for (ID, NAME, AUTHOR, SUBJECT, PRICE) in cursor:
    contacts.append({
        'ID': ID,
        'NAME': NAME,
        "AUTHOR": AUTHOR, 
        "SUBJECT": SUBJECT,
        "PRICE": PRICE
    })

cursor.close()
connection.close()
response = Response()
response.content_type ='application/json'
response.data = json.loads(json.dumps(contacts))
return response

app.run('0.0.0.0', 4000)
```

## And this is Output::

> [{u'PRICE': 9999.999, u'AUTHOR': u'AKSHAY', u'NAME': u'AKSHAY', u'ID':
>   4, u'SUBJECT': u'BIG_DATA'}, {u'PRICE': 123.456, u'AUTHOR': u'Yashwant
>   Kanetkar', u'NAME': u'Exploring C', u'ID': 1001, u'SUBJECT': u'C
>   Programming'}, {u'PRICE': 371.019, u'AUTHOR': u'Yashwant Kanetkar',
>   u'NAME': u'Pointers in C', u'ID': 1002, u'SUBJECT': u'C Programming'},
>   {u'PRICE': 334.215, u'AUTHOR': u'E Balaguruswami', u'NAME': u'ANSI C
>   Programming', u'ID': 1003, u'SUBJECT': u'C Programming'}, {u'PRICE':
>   140.121, u'AUTHOR': u'Dennis Ritchie', u'NAME': u'ANSI C Programming', u'ID': 1004, u'SUBJECT': u'C Programming'}, {u'PRICE': 417.764,
>   u'AUTHOR': u'Herbert Schildt', u'NAME': u'C++ Complete Reference',
>   u'ID': 2001, u'SUBJECT': u'C++ Programming'}, {u'PRICE': 620.665,
>   u'AUTHOR': u'Stanley Lippman', u'NAME': u'C++ Primer', u'ID': 2002,
>   u'SUBJECT': u'C++ Programming'}, {u'PRICE': 987.213, u'AUTHOR':
>   u'Bjarne Stroustrup', u'NAME': u'C++ Programming Language', u'ID':
>   2003, u'SUBJECT': u'C++ Programming'}, {u'PRICE': 525.121, u'AUTHOR':
>   u'Herbert Schildt', u'NAME': u'Java Complete Reference', u'ID': 3001,
>   u'SUBJECT': u'Java Programming'}, {u'PRICE': 575.651, u'AUTHOR': u'Cay
>   Horstmann', u'NAME': u'Core Java Volume I', u'ID': 3002, u'SUBJECT':
>   u'Java Programming'}, {u'PRICE': 458.238, u'AUTHOR': u'James Gosling',
>   u'NAME': u'Java Programming Language', u'ID': 3003, u'SUBJECT': u'Java
>   Programming'}, {u'PRICE': 567.391, u'AUTHOR': u'Peter Galvin',
>   u'NAME': u'Operatig System Concepts', u'ID': 4001, u'SUBJECT':
>   u'Operating Systems'}, {u'PRICE': 421.938, u'AUTHOR': u'Mauris J
>   Bach', u'NAME': u'Design of UNIX Operating System', u'ID': 4002,
>   u'SUBJECT': u'Operating Systems'}, {u'PRICE': 352.822, u'AUTHOR':
>   u'Uresh Vahalia', u'NAME': u'UNIX Internals', u'ID': 4003, u'SUBJECT':
>   u'Operating Systems'}, {u'PRICE': 872.652, u'AUTHOR': u'Ayn Rand',
>   u'NAME': u'Atlas Shrugged', u'ID': 8001, u'SUBJECT': u'Novell'},
>   {u'PRICE': 9999.999, u'AUTHOR': u'AKSHAY', u'NAME': u'AKSHAY', u'ID':
>   9001, u'SUBJECT': u'BIG_DATA'}]

Comment: Well, JSON is a string format by definition. What kind of output were you expecting?

Comment: JSON is encoded as a string. It's probably your browswer (or whatever you use to make requests) not interpreting it as json. For your browser, there might exist extensions doing just that, for example "JSON Viewer" for chrome and "JSON Beautify It" for firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing particularly wrong with your code, just remove the call to `json.loads()` so that the JSON encoded data is used as the response data.

Calling `json.loads()` will recreate and pass a Python data structure (list of dictionaries in this case) to the response, which will not serialise as valid JSON. In Python 2 it will serialise using the Python `repr()` format as produced by `str()` which will not always produce a JSON compatible string  (the `u''` string prefix for example is not valid JSON). In Python 3 is will probably cause an exception because it won't be able to convert to a bytes object.

You could improve the code by using [`flask.json.jsonify()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.json.jsonify) which will return a `Response` object with the correct content type header and a JSON body:

```
from flask.json import jsonify

@app.route("/contact")
def getContacts():
    # create contacts...
    return jsonify(contacts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok ,finally got the proper output::

```
/ 20171119101107
// http://localhost:4000/contact

[
  {
    "SUBJECT": "BIG_DATA",
    "PRICE": 9999.999,
    "AUTHOR": "AKSHAY",
    "ID": 4,
    "NAME": "AKSHAY"
  },
  {
    "SUBJECT": "C Programming",
    "PRICE": 123.456,
    "AUTHOR": "Yashwant Kanetkar",
    "ID": 1001,
    "NAME": "Exploring C"
  },
  {
    "SUBJECT": "C Programming",
    "PRICE": 371.019,
    "AUTHOR": "Yashwant Kanetkar",
    "ID": 1002,
    "NAME": "Pointers in C"
  },
```

I removed json.loads() and installed json viewer plugin.Thank you very much for help.

Comment: But i still don't understand  : Why this u" " was appearing in output,there is nothing as as such in database entries .

Comment: `mysql.connector` is returning unicode strings from the database as per the default settings for [`mysql.connector.connect()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) (see the Character Encoding section).

Comment: Thank you very much.I really appreciate it.